# How do Install and run python scripts for GIMP?

Tags: python, gimp, python3

There appear to be 2 directories where GIMP looks for plugins. One is `C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\lib\gimp\2.0\plug-ins` and C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\plug-ins

[image]

However, when I go look at the `plug-ins` folder, everything is a stand-alone executable, there are no python scripts.

I found a python script I'd like to run. The author says to jsut stick the python source code file in the `plug-ins` folder and then the script be will be accessible in the GUI via The Menu `Xtns/Utils`. That does not seem right given what else is already in the `plug-ins` folder

```
'''GIMP plug-in to stitch two images together into a panorama.'''

abort = False

# These should all be standard modules
import sys
import os
import copy
import math
import struct
import time
import gimp
import gimpplugin
from gimpenums import *
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import cPickle as pickle

#------------ MAIN PLUGIN CLASS

class stitch_plugin(gimpplugin.plugin):
    '''The main plugin class defines and installs the stitch_panorama function.'''
    version = '0.9.6'
    def query(self):
        gimp.install_procedure("stitch_panorama",
                               "Stitch two images together to make a panorama",
                               "Stitch two images together to make a panorama (ver. " + \
                                stitch_plugin.version+")",
                               "Thomas R. Metcalf",
                               "Thomas R. Metcalf",
                               "2005",
                               "<Toolbox>/Xtns/Utils/Stitch _panorama",
                               "RGB*, GRAY*",EXTENSION,
                               [(PDB_INT32, "run-mode", "interactive/noninteractive"),
                               ],
                               [])

    # stitch_panorama is the main routine where all the work is done.

    def stitch_panorama(self, mode, image_list=None, control_points=None):
        '''Stitch together two images into a panorama.

        First get a set of "control points" which define matching
        locations in the two images.  Then use these control points to
        balance the color and warp the images into a third, panoramic
        image.'''

        if not abort:
            if not image_list: image_list = gimp.image_list()
            # Select which image is the reference and which is transformed.
            image_list=select_images(image_list,mode)
            if check_image_list_ok(image_list,mode):
                image_list[0].disable_undo()
                image_list[1].disable_undo()
                # fire up the user interface which does all the work.
                panorama = stitch_control_panel(control_points,image_list,mode)
                # clean up a bit
                for img in image_list:
                    if img:
                        img.clean_all()
                        img.enable_undo()
                        update_image_layers(img)  # is this necessary?
                gimp.pdb.gimp_displays_flush()
                return panorama

# Pau.

#------------ SUPPORTING CLASS DEFINITIONS

class control_point(object):
    '''Each control point gives matching locations in two images.'''
    def __init__(self,x1,y1,x2,y2,correlation=None,colorbalance=True):
        self.xy = (float(x1),float(y1),float(x2),float(y2))
        self.correlation = correlation
        self.colorbalance = colorbalance
    def x1(self): return self.xy[0]
    def y1(self): return self.xy[1]
    def x2(self): return self.xy[2]
    def y2(self): return self.xy[3]
    def cb(self):
        try:
            colorbalance = self.colorbalance
        except AttributeError:
            colorbalance = True
        return colorbalance
    def invert(self):
        try:
            colorbalance = self.colorbalance
        except AttributeError:
            colorbalance = True
        return control_point(self.x2(),self.y2(),self.x1(),self.y1(),
                                           self.correlation,colorbalance)

minradius = 20.0  # min radius for color averaging

class stitchable(object):
    '''Two images and their control points for stitching.'''
    def __init__(self,mode,rimage,timage,control_points=None):
        self.mode = mode                       # Mode: interactive/noninteractive
        self.rimage = rimage                   # the reference image object
        self.timage = timage                   # the transformed image object
        self.cimage = None                     # temporary image for correlation
        self.dimage = None                     # temporary image for undistorted image
        self.rimglayer = None                  # main image layer in reference image
        self.timglayer = None                  # main image layer in transformed image
        self.rcplayer = None                   # the reference control point display layer
        self.tcplayer = None                   # the transform control point display layer
        self.control_points = control_points   # the warping control points
        self.panorama = None                   # the resulting panoramic image
        self.rlayer = None                     # the reference layer in self.panorama
        self.tlayer = None                     # the transformed layer in self.panorama
        self.rmask = None                      # the reference layer mask
        self.tmask = None                      # the transformed layer mask
        self.rxy = None                        # x,y of reference corners [x1,y1,x2,y2]
        self.txy = None                        # x,y of transformed corners [x1,y1,x2,y2]
        self.interpolation = INTERPOLATION_CUBIC
        self.supersample = 1
        self.cpcorrelate = True                # correlate control points?
        self.recursion_level = 5
        self.clip_result = 1   # this must be 1 or gimp will crash (segmentation fault)
        self.colorbalance = True               # color balance?
        self.colorradius = minradius           # color radius
        self.blend = True                      # blend edges?
        self.blend_fraction = 0.25             # size of blend along edges (fraction of image size)
        self.rmdistortion = True               # remove distortion?
        self.condition_number = None           # the condition number of the transform
        self.progressbar = None                # the progress bar widget
        self.update()
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        '''Make the stitchable class indexable over the control points.'''
        return self.control_points[index]
    def update(self):
        if self.control_points:
            self.npoints = len(self.control_points)
            rarray,tarray = self.arrays()
            self.transform = compute_transform_matrix(rarray,tarray,self)
            self.errors = compute_control_point_errors(self)
        else:
            self.npoints = 0
            self.transform = None
            self.errors = None
    def set_control_points(self,control_points):
        '''Se the whole control point list.'''
        self.control_points = control_points
        self.update()
    def add_control_point(self,cp):
        '''Add a control point to the control_points list.
           The control_point parameter should be of the control_point
           class.'''
        assert cp.__class__ is control_point, \
               'control_point parameter is not an instance of the control_point class.'
        if self.control_points:
            self.control_points.append(cp)
        else:
            self.control_points = [cp]
        self.update()
    def delete_control_point(self,index):
        '''Delete a control point from the control point list.'''
        if self.control_points:
            self.control_points.pop(index)
            self.update()
    def replace_control_point(self,cp,index):
        '''Replace a control point in the control point list.'''
        if self.control_points:
            if index < len(self.control_points):
                self.control_points[index] = cp
                self.update()
    def move_control_point_up(self,index):
        if self.control_points:
            if index > 0 and index < self.npoints:
                cp1 = self.control_points[index]
                cp2 = self.control_points[index-1]
                self.control_points[index] = cp2
                self.control_points[index-1] = cp1
                self.update()
    def move_control_point_down(self,index):
        if self.control_points:
            if index >=0 and index <self.npoints-1:
                cp1 = self.control_points[index]
                cp2 = self.control_points[index+1]
                self.control_points[index] = cp2
                self.control_points[index+1] = cp1
                self.update()
    def inverse_control_points(self):
        '''Invert the control point list and return the inverse.'''
        inverse = []
        for c in self.control_points:
            inverse.append(c.invert())
        return inverse
    def arrays(self):
        '''Get the reference and transformed control points as lists.'''
        rarray = []
        tarray = []
        for i in range(self.npoints):
            rarray.append([self.control_points[i].x1(),self.control_points[i].y1(),1.0])
            tarray.append([self.control_points[i].x2(),self.control_points[i].y2(),1.0])
        return (rarray,tarray)
    def color(self,control_point,radius=minradius):
        '''Get the color values at a control point in each image.
           The return value is a two-element tuple in which each entry
           is a color tuple.'''
        assert control_point in self.control_points,'Bad control point'
        rnx = self.rimage.width   # the dimensions of the images
        rny = self.rimage.height
        tnx = self.timage.width
        tny = self.timage.height
        # Make sure that the radius is not so large that the
        # average circle extends beyond the edge.
        if radius > control_point.x1():
            radius = max(control_point.x1(),1.0)
        if radius > control_point.y1():
            radius = max(control_point.y1(),1.0)
        if control_point.x1()+radius > rnx-1:
            radius = max(rnx-control_point.x1()-1,1.0)
        if control_point.y1()+radius > rny-1:
            radius = max(rny-control_point.y1()-1,1.0)
        #if __debug__: print 'radius: ',radius,control_point.x1(),control_point.y1(),rnx,rny
        # the scale of the transformed image may be different from the scale of the
        # reference image.  So, the radius should be scaled as well.
        if self.transform:
            (sscale,srotation) = transform2rs(self.transform)
            tradius = max(radius/sscale,1.0)
        else:
            tradius = radius
        # Check size of tradius
        if tradius > control_point.x2():
            tradius = max(control_point.x2(),1.0)
            if self.transform: radius = max(tradius*sscale,1.0)
        if tradius > control_point.y2():
            tradius = max(control_point.y2(),1.0)
            if self.transform: radius = max(tradius*sscale,1.0)
        if control_point.x2()+tradius > tnx-1:
            tradius = max(tnx-control_point.x2()-1,1.0)
            if self.transform: radius = max(tradius*sscale,1.0)
        if control_point.y2()+tradius > tny-1:
            tradius = max(tny-control_point.y2()-1,1.0)
            if self.transform: radius = max(tradius*sscale,1.0)
        #if __debug__: print 'radius: ',tradius,control_point.x2(),control_point.y2(),tnx,tny
        ##if __debug__: print 'color radii are ',radius,tradius
        ##if __debug__:
        ##    print 'using a color radius of ',radius,tradius
        return ( gimp.pdb.gimp_image_pick_color(self.rimage,
                                                self.rimglayer,
                                                control_point.x1(),
                                                control_point.y1(),
                                                0, # use the composite image, ignore the drawable
                                                1,radius),
                 gimp.pdb.gimp_image_pick_color(self.timage,
                                                self.timglayer,
                                                control_point.x2(),
                                                control_point.y2(),
                                                0, # use the composite image, ignore the drawable
                                                1,tradius)
                )
    def cbtest(self,control_point):
        '''Get the color balance flag for a control point.'''
        assert control_point in self.control_points,'Bad control point'
        return control_point.cb()

    def cbtests(self):
        '''Get flag to determine if a control point will be used in the color balancing.'''
        return [self.cbtest(self.control_points[c])
                    for c in range(self.npoints)] # iterates over self.control_points

    def colors(self):
        '''Get the color values at all the control points.'''
        if self.errors:
            return [self.color(self.control_points[c],self.colorradius)
                    for c in range(self.npoints)] # iterates over self.control_points
        else:
            return [self.color(c) for c in self] # iterates over self.control_points

    def brightness(self,control_point,radius=minradius):
        '''Compute the brightness of a control point in each image.
           The return value is a two-element tuple in which the entries
           are the brightness of the two images in the stitchable object.'''
        c = self.color(control_point,radius)
        brightness1 = 0
        brightness2 = 0
        n = 0.0
        for b1,b2 in zip(c[0],c[1]):  # iterate over both image colors simultaneously
            brightness1 += b1
            brightness2 += b2
            n += 1.0
        # the brightness is the mean of the values
        return (int(round(brightness1/n)),int(round(brightness2/n)))
    def brightnesses(self):
        '''Get the brightness values at all the control points.'''
        if self.errors:
            return [self.brightness(self.control_points[c],self.colorradius)
                    for c in range(self.npoints)] # iterates over self.control_points
        else:
            return [self.brightness(c) for c in self] # iterates over self.control_points

    def value(self,control_point,radius=minradius):
        '''Compute the value of a control point in each image.
           The return value is a two-element tuple in which the entries
           are the value of the two images in the stitchable object.'''
        c = self.color(control_point,radius)
        # the value is the max of the color channels
        return ( max(c[0]), max(c[1]) )
    def values(self):
        '''Get the values at all the control points.'''
        if self.errors:
            return [self.value(self.control_points[c],self.colorradius)
                    for c in range(self.npoints)]
        else:
            return [self.value(c) for c in self] # iterates over self.control_points
```

Comment: "The author says to just stick the python source code file in the plug-ins folder " have you actually tried this to see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Gimp has the Python support built-in since Gimp 2.8. To check that it works:

- You should have the menu `Filters>Python-fu>Console`
- It should open a Python console.
- You should also have *Filters>Decor>Fog* (2.10) or *Filers>Render>Clouds>Fog* (2.8, from memory).

On the other hand your filter seems very old (2005, so contemporary of Gimp 2.2). The code above is incomplete, the full code is over 3800 lines (as retrieved [here](http://mirror74.boot-keys.org/Soft/Graphics/GIMP/Stich_Panorama/stitch_0.9.6.py)).

This full code registers properly, but the menu location is no longer allowed in Gimp, so the actual menu location is *Filters>Utils>Stitch panorama*.

The plugin starts in Gimp 2.10 but I didn't test further. This plugin could have been useful in 2005, but these days panorama stitching is much better done with [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).